# Can't remove old OneDrive account from Mac and sign in with new account

Tags: onedrive

I used to work for a company and used a company email to sign into OneDrive on my MacBook. I have since changed companies and the email I originally signed into OneDrive with no longer exists.

I want to sign into OneDrive with my new email, but I can't seem to remove the old email. I consistently get prompted to just sign in with the old account that doesn't exist, and can't figure out how to remove the old account.

When I try to click on "help and settings", the only option I am presented with is 'quit OneDrive'.

[image: Pic 1]

I've tried removing OneDrive from my computer using an app cleaner which supposedly removed all associated files, but when I re-downloaded OneDrive, I was still getting prompted to sign in with that old defunct email.

[image: Pic 2]

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the article "[Reset OneDrive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/reset-onedrive-34701e00-bf7b-42db-b960-84905399050c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us#ID0EBCAAA=Mac)".

- Quit OneDrive. (Select the cloud icon in the top tray, then select
  Settings > Quit OneDrive.)
- Find OneDrive in your Applications folder.
- Right-click OneDrive and select Show Package Contents.
- Browse to the Contents > Resources folder.
- Double-click **ResetOneDriveApp.command** (or
  **ResetOneDriveAppStandalone.command**, if you're using the standalone
  app).
- Start OneDrive and finish the setup process.

Comment: unfortunately for me, after trying this method, the old business email still appears on the list as the default choice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missed the part where this was on mac. My solution is for windows. Not sure how to delete my comment on this site.

I've been having this same issue and just figured it out.

- Right click on the OneDrive application in your hidden icons, located at the right of your task bar.
- Select Settings
- Go to the Account tab.
- Click unlink account.

This should automatically prompt you to a login page and you should be able to enter in your email address.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the instruction above I had to remove all records with old tenant id in the Keychain application. It helped me to login to the new OneDrive tenant.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1157275)